# Permissions question

Tags: plugins, membership

Is there a plug in that allows User A to only see and edit their own post and User B to see all posts from all users like User A. We have tried a few plug ins without success. Thoughts?

Comment: Be aware that questions asking for plugin recommendations are off topic per the [faq](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I've misunderstood something, but I'm pretty sure WordPress can do this without any plugins.

Just set User A as Author, and User B as Editor or Administrator.

PS. See Capability vs Role Table: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table